# Configuring a web-service as data source in jasper report

Tags: java, web-services, jasper-reports, datasource, jax-ws-customization

Can some one provide me with the steps to

> configure a web-service as a data source in jasper reports

I read about implementation of `custom data source` but could not find any example explaining the **steps** in detail.